# Azure database not working after deploying .net core react js project

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I am completely noob to Azure. When I try to publish .net core app on Azure. its published and interface is showing, but it seems like database is not working i am unable to submit form data. in console it gives 500 error.  here is the link:
[Azure site link](https://projectnavonboard.azurewebsites.net/show-products)

Comment: your API threw an error. We can't tell you what it is. It's your code. Either add in some logging or catch the exception and return it back to the front end.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few steps that you can follow to solve this.

1. Check your appsettings.json - Check whether you have put the connection string in your appsettings.json
2. Validate the connection string - This might be a result of a wrong connection string. You can get the correct connection string from the Azure Database. It's something similar to this (`Server=tcp:mssql-care-dev.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=sqldb-care-dev;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=MsSqlAdmin;Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;`)

Replace {your_password} with your actual password. And the SQL server name.

3. Add a debug point in your application. And then run the local application against the hosted database. This will give you an insight into what's happening.